# How to output the variable inside a bash resource in chef

Tags: chef-infra

I am unable to access the `rate` variable which is obtained from my `getsStats.sh` script. The script outputs all the haproxy statistics.

```
bash "get statistics" do
  cwd '/vagrant'
  code <<-EOH
    ./getsStats.sh
    if [ "$rate" -gt 20 ]; then
       echo "hi"
    else
       echo "Boo"
    fi
  EOH
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run Chef with the log level set to debug to see output from subcommands. The easiest way to do this is `chef-client -l debug`.